# Why JQuery Datepicker is malfunctioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have a page where I am adding textboxes using for loop. There is a table in which there will be 12 rows with 4 columns. In 2nd and 4th column, I have added datepicker which is showing up fine.

The problem is when I select a date from datepicker in 2nd column, the date gets set in 2nd column(correct) but when I select a date in 4th column, the date gets set in 2nd column(incorrect).

Here's is my code:

```
...

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th><center>Column1</center></th>
        <th><center>Column2</center></th>
        <th><center>Column3</center></th>
        <th><center>Column4</center></th>
    </tr>

    <?php

      for($i=0; $i<count($time_period); $i++) {

        $current_table = $table[$i];

        $result = $db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$current_table'");

        if($result->rowCount() > 0) {
          //Table Exists!

        ?>
        <tr>
          <td><center><?php echo $time_period[$i]; ?></center></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" autocomplete="off" name="date_receipt[]" value=""></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" autocomplete="off" name="cheque_amount[]" value=""></td>
          <td><input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" id="<?php echo $i; ?>" autocomplete="off" name="date_deposit[]" value=""></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
      }
      }

      ?>

</table>

...
```

JQuery Code to Add Datepicker

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $.datepicker.setDefaults(
      $.extend($.datepicker.regional[''])
    );
    $('.datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
  });
</script>
```

I don't know why this is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: You have two of the exact same elements with the same class and id.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek I removed the `id` and changed the `class` of one of the datepickers and now it is working.

Comment: It would help if you post a snippet from the _generated_ output instead of php code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had a similar issue.  Try giving them unique IDs and then using the IDs to select them in jQuery.

Reasoning: My guess is that .datepicker returns an array of the nodes, so when it gets clicked, it puts the value into the class.val which will be the first child in the array.

Update in response:

They both have the same id:

```
id="<?php echo $i; ?>
```

Not working: http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/k3hdzLre/3/
Working: http://jsfiddle.net/snlacks/k3hdzLre/4/

Because they both have the same ID, the browser is going to look through the class by ID (even though you didn't pass the ID), because this is faster.  The browser assumes IDs are unique.

Comment: That would be my guess too

Comment: I had tried that but it didn't work. I gave the first textbox the class of `datepicker` and the other textbox the class of `datepicker2` and added the same in JQuery but unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria A `class` isn't an `id`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek If I use `id` in place of `class`, `datepicker` will be added to only 1 textbox on the whole page. To add multiple datepickers, I am using `class`.

Comment: I added some more to my answer explaining.  Hope that helps!

Comment: Yes, the problem was the same id. I have removed it and now it's working. Thanks.